# Merge 2 columns from different SQL server table with empty lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

I have this query to achieve my goal:

```
SELECT 
    Datum, LeavetypeID 
FROM 
    Kalender 
INNER JOIN 
    VerlofLijn ON Kalender.ID = VerlofLijn.DagID 
WHERE 
    VerlofLijn.Persnummer = @pnummer;
```

So basically I have a calendar in the table `Kalender`.

Every day has a unique id(`Kalender.ID`). In a second table (`VerlofLijn`) the matching `Kalender.ID` is stored in `VerlofLijn.DagID`, together with the `leavetype` and the unique employee number `Persnummer`.

What I want to achieve is a query that loads all dates from the calendar, and - if the current logged-on employee has leave in the database - show this next to the correct date.

So if there is no leave at all in the database for this employee, I still need the calendar to show up so in a next step he can add leave to his personal calendar.

I could create a personal calendar for every employee, but there has to be a better way, without the overhead of storing way to much data in the database, which will make the query to take much more time to search and complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this query

```
SELECT 
    Datum, LeavetypeID 
FROM 
    Kalender 
LEFT JOIN 
    VerlofLijn 
ON Kalender.ID = VerlofLijn.DagID AND VerlofLijn.Persnummer = @pnummer;
```

**Explanation:**  As you mentioned

> i want to achieve is a query that loads all dates from the calendar

you should use     `Kalender   LEFT JOIN VerlofLijn`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LEFT OUTER JOIN like this?

```
SELECT 
    Datum, LeavetypeID 
FROM 
    Kalender 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   VerlofLijn ON Kalender.ID = VerlofLijn.DagID 
WHERE 
   VerlofLijn.Persnummer = @pnummer;
```

You get all the values from Kalendar even if there are no matches from the table VerlofLijn, and all the common values from VerlofLijn.

You can find some examples here: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)